# Perl one-liner to replace a code block

Tags: scripting, perl

I have a file `foo.txt`

```
hello world
      first line to change
        second line to change
```

I would like to write a perl one-liner that changes `foo.txt` to read

```
hello world
      this is
        my new text
```

I tried

```
perl -p -i -e 's/      first line to change\n        second line to change/      this is\n        my new text/g' foo.txt
```

but this script does nothing to the file. What's wrong with my one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `perl` read one line input at a time, so your regex never matches. For working with multiple lines input, you have two options.

Enable paragraph mode:

```
perl -i.bak -00pe ...
```

or slurp the whole file:

```
perl -i.bak -0777pe ...
```

(Any value above `-0400` will cause `perl` to slurp the whole file, `-0777` is used for convention)